# How to convert benzamide to benzylamine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, organic-reduction

> **Question**
>   Benzamide can be converted to benzylamine using
>
> A) $\ce{Br2,\ KOH}$
>    B) $\ce{PCl5}$
>    C) $\ce{LiAlH4}$
>    D) $\ce{NaBH4}$

**My answer:**

Reducing agent is used so C and D options both must be correct but since its single choice answer, I do not know which is more appropriate. Any help?
Also, what does option A and B reagents do to amides?

Comment: You're on the right track. $\ce{R-CONH2}$ is an electrophile. Is it more or less electrophilic than a ketone? Your reductions are nucleophilic additions to the amide, aren't they? Which of the hydrides is the stronger reagent here? Would the comparison of the electronegativities of boron and aluminium be helpful here?

Comment: Less electrophilic! So weaker hydride donor is used and so is the answer $\ce{NaBH4}$ ? @KlausWarzecha

Comment: +1 You have **correctly** assigned the electrophilicity and nucleophilicity but somehow came to the wrong conclusion :) For a ketone or aldehyde, I would indeed use $\ce{NaBH4}$: *Offer a reagent that is just strong enough*. The less electrophilic carbon in the amide requires the more reactive $\ce{LiAlH4}$ to add a $\ce{H-}$ there: *In your face, sluggish amide* ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Wouldn't the [HSAB principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory) say otherways?

Comment: Thank you @KlausWarzecha What is HSAB, Chemexchange?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Any help?

Comment: @ChemExchange It wouldn't BH3 is softer acid than AlH3, and H- is soft.

Comment: @Mithoron That wikipedia link says that hard refers to small species. Isn't H small?

Comment: @Mixcels It is - this theory is rather tricky - H has low electronegativity for an anion and H- is easily reducible.

Comment: @Mithoron So soft means which lose their charge easily? Table1 says H- is a soft base. According to the EN, you are correct but I don't understand why the theory says "hard refers to small".

Comment: It is basic rule - F- is small, hard; I- big, soft. Here's another link http://faculty.uml.edu/ndeluca/84.334/topics/Hard-Soft%20Acid-Base%20Theory.ppt

Comment: @Mithoron Looks like H- is an exception to it as it looks small but also soft. Thank you for your time.

Comment: $\ce{H-}$ is not small at all. Hydrogen atom is as big as oxygen. Its anion is even bigger. Imagine one positive charge vs two negative charge. Thus, $\ce{H-}$ is a very typical soft base: big and easy to be distorted. In this question, hard soft effect is really overwhelmed by the electronic effect as $H$ in $LAH$ has more partial negative charge than $H$ in $\ce{NaBH4}$.

Comment: I didn't know about the size. I thought since H was small so would be H-. Thank you for your update @IanFang

Comment: Thank you everyone. The above comment discussion helped me out. Thanks @Mithoron

Comment: LiAlH4 is corect answer.
It is stronger reducing agent, whereas NaBH4 is mild reducing agent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more reactive $\ce{LiAlH4}$ is required for the reduction of the amide to the corresponding amine ([source](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch22/ch22-2-2-4.html)). The carbonyl carbon of an [amide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amide) is less electrophilic compared to a ketone, because electron density is donated by the amide nitrogen via resonance.

Bromine and hydroxide react with an carboxylic acid amide to yield an amine with one fewer carbon atom ([Hofmann degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofmann_rearrangement)). $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{KOH}$ react to form $\ce{KOBr}$ in situ, which transforms the amide into an intermediate isocyanate ($\ce{R-N=C=O}$). Hydrolysis of the isocyanate yields a carbamic acid $\ce{R-NH-COOH}$, which decomposes to the amine $\ce{R-NH2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$. As described in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01172698), the reaction of $\ce{PCl5}$ with carboxylic acid amides produces amidochlorides $\ce{RCCl2NH2}$ as intermediates, which break down to the corresponding nitrile $\ce{RC#N}$ and $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: Is that carbamic acid decomposition instantaneous?

Comment: @Mixcels Yes, it is. Carbamic acid and many of its derivatives are generally unstable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbamic_acid).